# stat_density with Sheather Jones binwidth in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I saw the ggplot2 source hard codes `bw = "nrd0"`. Is there a way to change the binwidth to `bw = "SJ"` by passing an argument, or do I have to redefine the class with that difference?

I came up with an alternative whereby I build functions to pass to `stat_function`.

```
library(purrr)
fit <-
  Y %>%
  split(.$from) %>%
  map(~ density(x = .$dist, bw = "SJ")) %>%
  map(approxfun)
```

Where I call the function as:

```
...
Y %>%
ggplot(aes(x = x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = fit[[1]]) + 
  stat_function(fun = fit[[2]])
```

The downside is that I have to set every color manually.

Comment: I would just `edit()` the function; but I often have a similar problem in other cases, so if someone else has a handy suggestion, perhaps involving `formals`, I'd love to hear it!